# Wrong gcc version used during compilation

Tags: ubuntu, gcc, hpc, gem5

I'm installing gem5-gpu on the hpc of my college.

I've already loaded the gcc/4.9.2 module, and gcc -v also shows that the current gcc version is 4.9.2

```
gcc version 4.9.2 (GCC)
```

but when I tried to build gem5-gpu, there will be an error:

```
Error: gcc version 4.6 or newer required.
   Installed version: 4.4.7
```

Why would be such a conflict?

Answer (score 0):

The gcc command uses /usr/bin/gcc which is just a symbolic link

Enter command: ls -l /usr/bin/gcc

The output will be: lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 7 Mar  7 17:35 /usr/bin/gcc -> gcc-4.6

The -> show wich gcc it is pointing. you should change tha with ln command

look this: [ln document](http://www.computerhope.com/unix/uln.htm)

ln [OPTION]... TARGET [...] [LINKNAME [...]]

use: sudo ln -s {{path to gcc4.9 }} /usr/bin/gcc